# Redirect from a database on a server to a local for testing

Tags: c#, javascript, mysql, sql, logic

So I am assigned a projet on a company where I am to fix up and add some features as a side-project for the company. I have a almost complete website (13 000 lines of code or so) in C# and JavaScript. I have a local copy of the website and the database and I want to just toy around with my local database so I can try things out and not ruin the entire website/database.

I am relatively new to JavaScript and I kind of understand C# by now. I think I have found where I am supposed to change the database connection but not sure how I am supposed to do it, or what to change it to. The local database is on my desktop, next to the local copy of the project if that helps. This is where I figured I should change:

```
<connectionStrings> 
    <!--add name="MySqlConnection" connectionString="DATA SOURCE=11.11.111.11;
        DATABASE=websitename;USER ID=websitename;PASSWORD=xxxxxx;PORT=1234"/-->
    <add name="MySqlConnection" connectionString="DATA SOURCE=localhost;
        DATABASE=websitename;USER ID=username;PASSWORD=xxxxxxx;PORT=1234"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Also: shouldn't I be able to test this locally when I have no internet connection? Because right now it seems that I can't. Any tips are good tips. The weird thing is that the code wasn't runnable because of 2 errors (2 functions took 37 and 38 arguments instead of 38 and 39) and after I fixed that I could run the program in Visual Studio through Google Chrome. This should imply that the local code is running - right?
Well...if I change some hard-coded text on the website or add something in the menu it doesn't change when I run the program - this would imply that it's the version on the server running when I do it. But then why would it not run with the errors (that somehow doesn't bother the website for some reason)

I am very confused right now...sorry for a long post. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

lots of vague questions. Strip it down to essentials.

When you build the project in visual studio you can choose where to deploy it. It sounds like in IIS the folder is set to something other than your build folder (which is fine) but that means you have to redeploy when you build to see the changes.

if local host is requiring an internet connection make sure your hosts file in windows is configured properly.

you found the right area (maybe) for hte connection string - depends on how its coded up in the app though. It doesn't look like you are using a sql server database though because you have no provider info in the string. So you need to break this into several questions because there could be a chunk of code for each part.

Answer (score 0):

If your live and local database stored information is not parallel then For testing purpose generate a database script from live database with schema and data.Then deploy it to local IIS.There is no need for internet for localhost database.